# Repository and Unit of work patern without Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, repository-pattern

I am developing one application in MVC4 with sybase as database. I am not using Enterprise library for database activity and not using any ORM tools like Entity Framework.

I want to implement Repository and Unit of work patern in this application for models. But on internet all application sample i found uses entity framework.

Please help me to achieve repository patern without entity framework.

Comment: You can try NHibernate.

Comment: Not sure if this helps but try this [link](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc01776.1600/doc/html/san1357754863708.html), sybase support for entityframework

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. If you want something small and easy to pick up, try ServiceStack's ORMLite

Answer (score 1):

Repository pattern is unrelated to ORM or the db you're using. You simply define an interface that works with your business objects (save/get) and implement it in DAL.

The Repository implementation will just use whatever you have to access the db (ado.net, a micro orm,  full ORM), really it's just a class working with the db saving and restoring business objects. Nothing special, nothing magic.